# How to jump to top of page when routing WITHOUT using scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll

I'm building a React application where I have footer links that when clicked, take the user to the bottom of whatever page they're clicking. I want to change it so that when these links are clicked, the user is automatically taken to the top of the new page.

I already tried a solution of automatically scrolling to the top of the page, which WORKS, but the issue is that I have smooth scrolling set for my website because I have some buttons that scroll to certain parts of the page clicked, and I want that animation to be smooth. However, for this particular function, I don't want smooth scroll because I don't want the user to see that they were taken to the bottom of a page then scrolled up.

This is my current code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}, [])
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this without using scroll so that I can avoid having to display the smooth scrolling behavior?

Comment: have a better smooth scroll that doesn't take over normal scrolling?

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding behaviour as instant in scrollTo function and do let me know if it works

```
useEffect(() => {
     window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "instant"
    });
}, [])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'auto'
});
```

Should hopefully remove the smooth action.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera

document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
```

Comment: The css property `scroll-behaviour` is still set to smooth, and this would still go smooth, which he doesn't want.

Comment: good catch, he could always remove that attribute and add it once we are scrolled to the top already.

Comment: I already left an answer down below bypassing the CSS property (:

Comment: thats awesome, keep doing the great job so we can make this community better